# PostgreSQL - How to avoid too many JOINs?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, where-clause

We have `company_employee_count` table tracking employee count by quarter. Table has a column for previous quarter count to quickly identify
the quarters in which employee count has increased or decreased compared to previous quarter. Now we need to write a SQL query to find
the companies that have consistently increased employee count in the last N quarters. i.e. if we pass four quarters 2019_Q1, 2019_Q2, 2019_Q3, 2019_Q4
quarters, we want to get the companies that have `employee_count` in all four quarters and current quarter count is more than previous quarter.

```
    TABLE company_employee_count{
    company_id
    employee_count
    quarter (Stored as 2019_Q1, 2019_Q2)
    prev_quarter_employee_count
    }
```

We are using postgresql.
I am currently using a query like this which has JOINs on each quarter data.

```
select * from
(select employee_count,company_id from company_employee_count where quarter='2019_Q4') as q4_19
inner join
(select employee_count,company_id from company_employee_count where quarter='2019_Q3') as q3_19
on q4_19.company_id=q3_19.company_id
inner join 
(select employee_count,company_id from company_employee_count where quarter='2019_Q2') as q2_19
on q2_19.company_id=q3_19.company_id
inner join
(select employee_count,company_id from company_employee_count where quarter='2019_Q1') as q1_19
on q2_19.company_id=q1_19.company_id
where 
q4_19.employee_count > q3_19.employee_count and 
q3_19.employee_count > q2_19.employee_count and
q2_19.employee_count > q1_19.employee_count
```

I want to avoid JOINing quarterly data and be able to somehow leverage `prev_quarter_employee_count`.

Appreciate any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation and a subquery:

```
select c.*
from (select company_id,,
             max(employee_count) filter (where quarter = '2019_Q4') as q4_19,
             max(employee_count) filter (where quarter = '2019_Q3') as q3_19,
             max(employee_count) filter (where quarter = '2019_Q2') as q2_19,
             max(employee_count) filter (where quarter = '2019_Q1') as q1_19
      from company_employee_count
      where quarter in ('2019-Q1', '2019-Q2', '2019-Q3', '2019-Q4')
      group by company_id
     ) c
where q4_19 > q3_19 and q3_19 > q2_19 and q2_19 > q1_19
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your quick answer. Your solution looks simpler and more readable. But, I tried your solution instead of joins but performance hasn't improved. Data keeps on increasing every quarter. Is there any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: @ShanmukhMeesala . . . A `WHERE` clause limiting the number of quarters being processed should help.

Comment: Thank you! Just FYI I have indexes on quarter and company_id... and partition on quarter.

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff, When I use "filter" for some reason Postgres' "Partition pruning" is not working. It's scanning all the partitions. I'm using Postgres 11.6 FYI.
Appreciate your help, Thanks!

Comment: @ShanmukhMeesala . . . The partition pruning should be occurring the the non-`filter` `where` clause:  `where quarter in ( . . .  )`.  If that is not pruning, then something is amiss with the definition of the partitions.

Comment: Awesome! Got the issue... I was missing the where clause in my query.
Thank you so much!!